# PHP form Echo change format

Tags: php

I have a mobile number

0827910119

this is how it is saved in SQL, if I echo it back on a form i would like to have it shown as follow

27827910119

This is my echo command

```
 <input type="text" name="member_msisdn" value="<? echo $rows['member_msisdn']; ?>" 
 readonly id="member_msisdn" />
```

I have tried a Session command to drop the 0 and add the 27 in front but not getting it to work

```
 $_SESSION['msisdn'] = "27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);
```

Is there another way I can echo the number to drop the 0 and add the 27 as I need the 27827910119 in my action PHP to work and not the 0827910119 number

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error? There is nothing wrong with `"27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);` assuming `$rows['member_msisdn'] = "0827910119"`.

Comment: I am not getting an error at all it is just not doing it. I have placed the Session variable at the beginning of the PHP code am I placing at the wrong place should I put it with the echo row?

Comment: Start by figuring out what your actual problem is. It doesn't seem to be about formatting anymore, but the fact that you can't set a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 $rows['member_msisdn'] = "27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);
```

instead of

```
$_SESSION['msisdn'] = "27" . substr($rows['member_msisdn'], 1);
```

or print using

```
<? echo $_SESSION['msisdn']; ?>
```

Comment: BTW: Don't use `$_SESSION['msisdn']` if the phone number should only be printed during the current request and not be stored for the next request.